# Application.Restart not passing arguments back

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, clickonce

This is a ClickOnce application. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.APPLICATION.RESTART%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true), "*If your application was originally supplied command-line options when it first executed, Restart will launch the application again with the same options.*". But I don't know if this is supposed to work or not with ClickOnce applications. If so, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();         
    textBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, GetCommandLineFile());
}

private static string[] GetCommandLineFile()
{
    if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain != null &&
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation != null &&
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments != null &&
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData != null &&
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData.Any())
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData;
    }
    else return new string[] { };
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Restart();
}
```

I associated my application with the `.abc` extension and when I double click my `.abc` file, the application will launch with the file name as the only argument, but then when I restart (by pressing my `button1`), `GetCommandLineFile()` will return an empty array.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I need my application to restart using the same arguments. Just calling Application.Restart() definitely does *not* pass the same arguments through (at least not when using ClickOnce). I can't find any other way to do this either. The Restart() method does not let you pass new arguments and calling Process.Start is no good because if you're restarted because of an update the executable path will change, and I can't find anyway to get the path of the .appref-ms

Comment: My workaround is to write the commandline arguments to a file the data directory before i update/restart and if no command line arguments come through after the restart it checks if the arguments file exists. if it does it loads the arguments from the file and deletes the file.

Comment: Yea I ended up doing something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `Application.Restart` was designed for standard command line arguments instead of how ClickOnce applications handle it.

Looking at Microsoft's code for `Application.Restart`, they explicitly check if the application is a ClickOnce application and then restart it **without** any arguments being passed.  Any other application, gets `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` parsed and sent to a new process.

I think a better solution, instead of writing arguments to a file, is to simply start a new process as such :

```
"path\Application Name.appref-ms" arg1,arg2,arg3
```

That way, when your application starts up, `GetCommandLineFile()` should grab the arguments again.